# How to get unique data when comparing the data from excel and the data from the database

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import

I am trying to import an excel sheet in Laravel, but the problem is that if a user accidentally imports the same excel sheet or if he imports another excel sheet that has the same data like the one in the database then the data will be duplicated and I wanted to avoid that so I wanted to do some kind of validation before importing the data

I have tried getting the data from the database and the data form excel and joining them in an array and using the php function array_unique() but it shows the error array to string conversion

My route:

```
//Uploading Excel Routes
Route::get('/cvs/upload','UploadController@index');
Route::post('/cvs/uploadFile','UploadController@csvfileupload');
```

My controller

```php
public function csvfileupload(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('submit') != null ){
            $file = $request->file('file');
            // File Details
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $tempPath = $file->getRealPath();
            $fileSize = $file->getSize();
            $mimeType = $file->getMimeType();

            // Valid File Extensions
            $valid_extension = array("csv");

            // 2MB in Bytes
            $maxFileSize = 2097152;

            // Check file extension
            if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$valid_extension)){
                // Check file size
                if($fileSize <= $maxFileSize){
                    // File upload location
                    $location = 'uploads';
                    // Upload file
                    $file->move($location,$filename);
                    // Import CSV to Database
                    $filepath = public_path($location."/".$filename);
                    // Reading file
                    $file = fopen($filepath,"r");
                    $importData_arr = array();
                    $i = 0;

                    while (($filedata = fgetcsv($file, 1300, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                        $num = count($filedata );
                        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                            $importData_arr[$i][] = $filedata [$c];
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                    // Check For Unique Values On Excel Sheet
                    $tempArr = array_unique(array_column($importData_arr, 1));

                    $vals = array_intersect_key($importData_arr, $tempArr);

                    // Get Current Time
                    $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();

                    // Insert The values in the Categories Table
                        foreach ($vals as $importData) {
                            $insertData = array("categories_name" => str_slug($importData[1]), "created_at" => $mytime->toDateTimeString());
                            Categories::insert($insertData);
                        }

                    Session::flash('message','Import Successful.');
                }else{
                    Session::flash('message','File too large. File must be less than 2MB.');
                }
            }else{
                Session::flash('message','Invalid File Extension.');
            }
        }
        // Redirect to index
        return redirect()->action('UploadController@index');
    }
}
```

My view file:

```php
@section('content')
    <!-- Message -->
    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <p >{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    @endif
    <center>
        <!-- Form -->
        <form action="/cvs/uploadFile" method="post" class="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type='file' name='file' >
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Import'>
        </form>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your column with index `1` must be unique.

So, why not use it for key of array? That will be mean that function `array_unique` not needed.

```
while (($filedata = fgetcsv($file, 1300, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($filedata);
    $row = [];
    for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $row[] = $filedata[$c];
    }
    // Here we set array with unique column like key
    $importData_arr[$row[1]] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

This code would be replace for

```
$tempArr = array_unique(array_column($importData_arr, 1));

$vals = array_intersect_key($importData_arr, $tempArr);
```

And instead `$vals` you must use to `$importData_arr`.

Comment: ok. But how can I get the unique data between the excel sheet and the database

Comment: When you got your array with unique keys, you can do one request to your table and get all rows, which contain keys from `$importData_arr`.
It will be like `$exists = Categories::where('column', array_keys($importData_arr))->get(['column'])->keyBy('column');`

Then, when you go for your array for insert, add check: `foreach ($importData_arr as $key => $importData) { if (array_key_exists($key, $exists)) continue; ...`